# How to prove $P[X\geq u]\geq \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-e^{-u^2}})$ when $X$ is standard normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

If $X$ is a standard normal random variable, I read that $$P[X\geq u]\geq \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-e^{-u^2}}).$$

How to prove that?

Comment: The easy bit is to show it is true for $u=0$ and $u<0$.  It is also not difficult for $u>1$, by considering derivatives.

Comment: @Henry the derivative is $\frac{-u\cdot e^{-u^2}}{2\sqrt{1-e^{-u^2}}}$. should i compare this to the derivative of $(2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_u^\infty e^{-u^2/2}du$ which is $-\sqrt{\frac{e^{-u^2}}{2\pi}}$?

Comment: something like that